# How to fill data automatically in a textfield using the info provided in the <select> tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to fill data automatically in a textfield using the info provided in the  tab using javascript. And also the filled  data cannot be edited.

The textfield may fill data based on calculation on the option selected in  tab.

Please help.

Comment: Please post your code and show what you have made so far.

Comment: Post the code you already have...

Comment: <form action=" ">

<select name="field4" class="select-field">
     <option value="select">- - select - -</option>
     <option value="2">less than 2kg</option>
     <option value="3">2kg - 3kg</option>
     <option value="4">3kg - 4kg</option>
</select>

<label for="field1"><span>Price <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field1" value="" /></label>
</form>  

Now i want that based on the selection from the drop down list the price will be filled automatically in the text box. And also the text field value is not editable by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't so much understand your question but try this:
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="t" disabled />
```

**JS**

```
var text = document.getElementById('t');

text.value = 658.57; // your calc result
```

Comment: Here's my `code`

<form>

<select name="field4" class="select-field">
     <option value="2">less than 2kg</option>
     <option value="3">2kg-3kg</option>
     <option value="4">3kg-4kg</option>
</select>

<label for="field1"><span>Price</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field1"/></label>
</form>

Now i want that based on the selection from the drop down list the price will be filled automatically in the text box (Price). Also this value is not editable by the user. For Eg: if i select "2kg-3g" from the drop down list, the text should show 100 and this value is not editable.

Comment: You will have to use an if-else statement to choose the value to set in the textbox in js. The if-else statement should run each time the user selects a value from the options field

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var VALUE_OF_SELECTED_TAB = this.value;
    // HERE DO YOUR CALCULATIONS
    $(YOUR_SELECT_ELEMENT).on('change', function() {
        $(YOUR_TEXTFIELD_ELEMENT).html(
            '<input type="text" value="'+ YOUR_CALCULATION_RESULT 
                +'" class="field left" readonly="readonly" >');
    });
});
```